# jqm ignoring data-role = 'header'

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have applied a data-role = 'header' to a jqm 'page', but the header doesn't work. In firebug I can see that the header div does NOT have the ui-header-fixed class applied to it.

I'm using jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js.

In this example you can see I *even* hard-coded the class into the div (only for testing), but jqm removes it!

I have a:

```
<div id              = 'page_home_header_div'                             
     data-role       = 'header'                                                       
     data-position   = 'fixed'                                                       
     data-tap-toggle = 'false'                                                       
     data-theme      = 'a'                                                            
     class           = 'ui-headerfixed'   
  >
```

Why would jqm ignore data-role = 'header'?

---

**EDIT**: all the other jqm stuff is working: styles, DOM changes, pageinit events, etc

Comment: Are you files: jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js, and the related css file getting loaded?

Comment: ... I will go verify ... 5 minutes ...

Comment: PLease can you post a jsfiddle.net where this problem is reproducible?

Comment: ANSWER ... this had nothing to do with jqm or my site. Instead, the UserAgentSwitcher that I was using on my firefox browser was creating the problem whenever I had it set to "mobile". Once I uninstalled the useragent extension, my site worked as expected. I would also note that this problem just began suddenly ... apparently the useragent extension must have updated recently. ... ... How would this affect the parsing/rendering of my jqm DOM: I don't know.